# Is it possible to filter a numeric column for values starting with a specific number, without using a helper column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel data where one column has numeric values of varying lengths, with sample values like 100, 100001, 11050, 201, 222001, etc.

I want to filter values starting with 1. I am able to do it using a helper column. But I am curious to know whether it is possible without a helper column? I tried Number Filters->Custom Filter->begins with 1, but this filter displayed 0 rows.

Comment: If you store the numbers as Text, then you can use the "begins with" filter. However, you would lose other functionality that only work with numbers. I would either use a helper column, or, duplicate that column and format the copy as text (ie, two formats of the same column). So, Col_as_Nbr and Col_as_Txt

Comment: I want to retain the column as Numeric and do not want to add helper column. Excel's Number Filters->Custom Filter has a "begins with" filter. Why does it not work when this option is under Number Filters?

Comment: Sadly, I think that drop-down list is default and misleading. You cannot use "begins with" or "contains" or several other options when working with numbers. Some of those are reserved for Text.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to add wildcard *, that use `1*` to filter the column.

[image]